# Get the latest record and its details of every id - linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have these three tables:

```
Item
id, name, isDeleted, typeId

ItemType
id, name, isDeleted

Item_Quantity
itemId, as_of(datetime), quantity 
//the sample data
1, 2017-09-19, 55
2, 2017-08-21, 37
1, 2017-09-20, 49
```

I want to create a LINQ query where I will be able to get the **id, name, typeId, the most recent date in as_of, and its quantity as of that time**

I tried doing it, but this is all I've got. I'm new to asp.net and LINQ, so I really have no idea what I'm doing.

```
var list = db.Items.Where(c => c.id == 0).GroupBy(c => c.id);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Item` entity has a collection property for `ItemQuantities`

```
public class Item
{
   public int Id { set;get; }
   public string Name { set;get; }
   public int ItemTypeId { set;get;} 
   public virtual ItemType ItemType { set;get; }
   public ICollection<ItemQuantity> ItemQuantities { set; get; }
}
public class ItemType
{
   public int Id { set;get; }
   public string Name { set;get; }
}   
public class ItemQuantity
{
   public int Id { set;get; }
   public DateTime AsOf { set;get ;}
   public int Qunatity { set;get;}
   public int ItemId { set;get; }
   public virtual Item Item { set;get; }
}
```

You can query the db.Items collection and sort the `ItemQuantities` property of each item by the `AsOf` value and take the first item.

So create a view model to represent this data

```
public class ItemVm
{
   public int Id { set; get; } 
   public string Name  { set;get; }
   public string ItemTypeName { set;get; }
   public DateTime? RecentOrderDate  { set;get; }
   public double? Qty { set;get;}
}
```

Now in the Linq query, project to this new view model.

```
var items =  db.Items.Select(g => new ItemVm
{
    Id = g.Id,
    Name = g.Name,Id
    ItemTypeName= g.ItemType.Name,
    RecentOrderDate = g.ItemQuantities.Any()? 
                g.ItemQuantities.OrderByDescending(q=>q.AsOf).FirstOrDefault().AsOf
               :(DateTime?)null,
    Qty = g.ItemQuantities.Any() ?
                g.ItemQuantities.OrderByDescending(q => q.AsOf).FirstOrDefault().Quantity
               :(int?) null,

}).ToList();
```

The above code will create a list of our new view model class objects. So if you are using this code inside an action method and passing to the view, you need to make sure you update your view so that it is now strongly typed to a collection of `ItemVm`

```
return View(items);
```

and your view will be

```
@model List<ItemVm>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between double and int` in the `Qty` part of the code.

Comment: change `(int?) null` to `(double?) null`

Comment: I got this exception: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List``1[<>f__AnonymousType1``6[System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32,System.String,System.Nullable``1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable``1[System.Double]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[WebProg.Models.Item]'.`

Comment: See the update in the answer. You need to make sure you are view is strongly typed to the same type. I updated the answer to use a view model.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. But I still don't understand how the `RecentOrderDate` and `Qty` worked. Can you explain it to me, if you don't mind?